# Cómo ajustar márgenes de un elemento con float

Tags: html, css, flexbox, posicionamiento

Estoy intentando alinear una serie de elementos en una página y estoy teniendo complicaciones.

De momento quiero dividir la web en estos dos trozos, (80%,20%) cosa que he conseguido con éxito.

El caso es que ahora quiero ajustar los márgenes, pero parece que las propiedades float `left` y `right` los anulan ¿Es esto así o lo estoy haciendo yo mal? ¿En el caso de que sea así, cuál sería la mejor alternativa (para mantener el diseño pero poder jugar con los bordes)?

```css
.sidebar{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
float: right;
text-align: center;
width: calc(20% - 30px);
background: lightgray;
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
margin-right: 30px;
}

   .contenido{
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold;
float: left;
width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
        <h3 class="subtitulo_etiqueta">MÁS ENCUESTAS</h3>
        <div class="mas_encuestas">
            Breve descripción de diversas encuestas que abarcan nombrosos temas
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <article class="encuesta"> <h2> Primera encuesta</h2> <hr style=" float: left; position: relative;bottom: 10px; width: 75%;">
        <div class="contenido">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con algunos pequeños detalles ya estaría solucionado el diseño, con los `float`. Simplemente calcular el ancho perfecto de ambos: `article` y `sidebar`.

Para arreglar un poco el diseño, cambie algunas pequeñas cosas y deje de una forma básica, donde puedes abanzar desde ahí con tu estructura y diseño.

Lo que se calcula exactamente es el ancho de ambos: `sidebar`, *20%* y `encuesta`, *80%*. Pero en responsive ambos son del 100%.

Todo esta dentro del `main` (como debe ser) para acomodar ambos contenidos en sus márgenes y darle mejor apariencia (para éste ejemplo).

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

main {
display: block;
width: 90%;
margin: auto;
padding: 1em 0;
}

.sidebar {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
float: right;
width: calc(20% - 30px);
padding: 1em;
background-color: lightgray;
}

.encuesta {
display: block;
float: left;
width: calc(80%);
padding: 1em;
background-color: lightgreen;
}

.divisor {
position: relative;
width: 75%;
margin: 10px 0;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {

.sidebar, .encuesta {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

}
```

```html
<main>

<div class="sidebar">
    <h3>Más encuestas</h3>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque fugit animi hic aliquam dolores neque iste corrupti illo laudantium ullam asperiores dolorum in recusandae, sit sint quis ratione maiores. Enim!
    </p>
</div>

<article class="encuesta">
    <h2>Primera encuesta</h2>
    <hr class="divisor">
    <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur saepe minima ducimus animi facere itaque tempore incidunt, quisquam deserunt iste.
    </p>
</article>

</main>
```

Comment: Si es lo correcto, marca ésta respuesta con *√* para que sirva a otros que necesiten.